# I get an error invalid format at initial stage after kali linux logo

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux

I get an `error invalid format` at initial stage in Kali Linux and screen goes blue. How can i solve this issue? Dual boot Kali install. I am new to use Kali Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, please post an **accurate** error message, more info about circumstances when it started happening and what you attempted to fix the issue other than asking here.

Comment: Kali linux not run, show error invalid format and screen goes blue

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is that the Kali install did not expect Secure Boot (and possibly even UEFI) to be enabled.

If you are learning Kali for the first time, don't bash your main system trying to dual boot Kali.  It is app heavy and friendliness short. You may wind up having to reinstall your host system.

Set up Kali in a Virtual Machine environment (VMware preferred as Kali needs special settings for Hyper-V).  This is the very best way to learn Kali.

I am in a Kali V2023.1 machine here and posted from Kali.

VMware allows USB Pass Through for which you can use a Wireless Card that supports Monitor Mode.  I do this.

Comment: "friendliness short" :-D